# How to get cognitive services account key using powershell function app?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cognitive-services, azure-function-app

I have created cognitive services account . I want to get cognitive services account key and store it in a variable using powershell script.

I have used below script :

```
$resourceGroup = "Demo"

$AccountName = "DemoCs"

$Key = Get-AzCognitiveServicesAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $AccountName

Write-Host "account key 1 = " $Key
```

after executing the script result is :

**2020-05-20T08:30:31Z   [Information]   INFORMATION: account key 1 =  Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.CognitiveServices.Models.PSCognitiveServicesAccountKeys**

Above script is able to list keys in the cloud shell but not in powershell function app .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply call `Import-Module Az.CognitiveServices` like on your local machine where you have previously installed `Az.CognitiveServices` from that site. But you have to copy all files from that locally installed package into specific folder inside of your Function App in Azure.

1.Install `Az.CognitiveServices` in local and go to its folder to get all the content in it.

2.Go to your function KUDU. Click `CMD>site>wwwroot>yourFunctionName` then create a directory called `modules`.

3.Simply **drag-and-drop** all files from your local powershell module location to your Azure Function App folder create above(modules).

4.Include `Az.CognitiveServices` PowerShell module in run.ps1 file like that example below:

```
Import-Module "D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\modules\Az.CognitiveServices.psd1"
```

5.Then run the script as below with `$Key.Key1` to specify the Key1.

```
$Key = Get-AzCognitiveServicesAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $AccountName

Write-Host "account key 1 = " $Key.Key1
```

For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://rasper87.wordpress.com/2019/01/25/import-powershell-module-package-into-azure-function/) and this [one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/using-powershell-modules-in-azure-functions/).